# One variable used in different programs in Canopy

Tags: python, ipython, enthought

I have a program computing multiple arrays, which I would like to use in another program. Is that possible?

Basically, is it possible in Canopy to use a variable created in another python file without using the white command prompt at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "without using the white command prompt at the bottom of the screen?" and why this is important. Otherwise, I agree with @FLab's comment pointing to another question.

Comment: For the moment I execute my program with Ctrl+A and then Ctrl+Shift+R to execute it in this command prompt, and not execute the program itself. So that's not convenient.
Reading the link from FLab, I think using `from data import *` in my main program will be sufficient to access the variables in data.py